# How to multiply nested lists by a list with the same length?

Tags: list-manipulation

Here's the expected output:

```
{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}} * {3, 4} = {{3a, 4b}, {3c, 4d}, {3e, 4f}}
```

However, the code above will multiply each element of the encompassing list (3 elements) by `{3, 4}` (2 elements) and cause an error.

I've tried defining a function and using `Map`, but I'm sure there's a more elegant way of doing this speedily, without needing to first define a function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
{3, 4} # & /@ {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}
```

> {{3 a, 4 b}, {3 c, 4 d}, {3 e, 4 f}}

Alternative forms:

```
Map[{3, 4} # &][{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}]
```

> {{3 a, 4 b}, {3 c, 4 d}, {3 e, 4 f}}

```
Map[{3, 4} # &, {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}]
```

> {{3 a, 4 b}, {3 c, 4 d}, {3 e, 4 f}}

Comment: Works perfectly. If anyone else is wondering, the multiplication sign is not required here, but you can also modify this to perform other basic operations such as addition by placing the operator between the slot: `{3, 4} + #`. Or to add subtract square root: `{3, 4} - Sqrt[#]`.

Answer (score 10):

```
{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}.DiagonalMatrix[{3, 4}]
```

> {{3 a, 4 b}, {3 c, 4 d}, {3 e, 4 f}}

Answer (score 6):

A fairly straightforward method is to use [`ScalingTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingTransform):

```
ScalingTransform[{3,4}] @ {{a,b},{c,d},{e,f}}
```

> {{3 a, 4 b}, {3 c, 4 d}, {3 e, 4 f}}

It is not as fast as using a double [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose) (@Thies) or [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot) (@Henrik) though:

```
list = RandomReal[1, {10^6, 3}];
scale = RandomReal[1, 3];

r1 = list . DiagonalMatrix[scale]; //RepeatedTiming
r2 = Transpose[scale Transpose[list]]; //RepeatedTiming
r3 = ScalingTransform[scale] @ list; //RepeatedTiming

r1 === r2 === r3
```

> {0.0075, Null}
>
> {0.018, Null}
>
> {0.2, Null}
>
> True

Answer (score 4):

```
Inner[Times, {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}, {3, 4}, List]
```

Answer (score 4):

With `Threaded` since V 13.1:

```
{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}} * Threaded[{3, 4}]
```

{{3 a, 4 b}, {3 c, 4 d}, {3 e, 4 f}}

Answer (score 3):

Dear @WeavingBird1917 you can use Table for your purpose.

```
list={{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};

result=Table[
{3*list[[i,1]],4*list[[i,2]]}
,{i,1,Length[list]}
]
```

If you want to change multiplication with summation, subtraction or division, you need only change the * sign with +, - or /.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `Transpose` to bring the matrix into a shape where the multiplication by `{3,4}` vectorises over the columns and then `Transpose` again to bring it back into the original shape:

```
Transpose[{3, 4} Transpose[{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}]]
```

> {{3 a, 4 b}, {3 c, 4 d}, {3 e, 4 f}}

or if we want to save a level of paranthesis, we can use the <kbd>Esc</kbd>`tr`<kbd>Esc</kbd> shortcut to get the postfix version of `Transpose`:

`Transpose[{3, 4} {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}`<kbd>Esc</kbd>`tr`<kbd>Esc</kbd>`]`

> {{3 a, 4 b}, {3 c, 4 d}, {3 e, 4 f}}

If we find ourselves using the double transpose pattern a lot we could also make this into a neat operator:

```
Transposed[f_Function] := Transpose[f[Transpose[#]]] &
Transposed[{3, 4} # &][{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}]
```

> {{3 a, 4 b}, {3 c, 4 d}, {3 e, 4 f}}

Answer (score 1):

Another method with [`Query`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html):

```
Query[All, {1->(3#&),2->(4#&)}]@{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}

(* {{3 a,4 b},{3 c,4 d},{3 e,4 f}} *)
```

'Under the hood' `Query` is using [`RightComposition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RightComposition.html) and [`MapAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html):

```
Query[All, {1->(3#&),2->(4#&)}]//Normal

(* MapAt[4 #1&,{All,2}]/*MapAt[3 #1&,{All,1}]  *)
```

```
MapAt[4 #1&,{All,2}]/*MapAt[3 #1&,{All,1}]@{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}

(* {{3 a,4 b},{3 c,4 d},{3 e,4 f}} *)
```